# Аналог std::this_thread::yield();

Tags: python, c++, yield

За вчерашний день я перепробовал множество аналогов yield из с++. Но мой код не работает как код на плюсах. Попрошу помощи здесь, знающие люди, пожалуйста подскажите аналог yield из ++ на python.
Пример с yield в c++

```
auto iDesiredCmdNumber   = g_Memory.Read<int32_t>(m_pClientState + g_Offsets.m_dwClientState_LastOutgoingCommand) + 2;
auto pOldUserCmd         = Input.m_pCommands         + ((iDesiredCmdNumber-1) % 150) * sizeof(UserCmd_t);
auto pVerifiedOldUserCmd = Input.m_pVerifiedCommands + ((iDesiredCmdNumber-1) % 150) * sizeof(VerifiedUserCmd_t);

// Method 1
auto pUserCmd = Input.m_pCommands         + (iDesiredCmdNumber     % 150) * sizeof(UserCmd_t);
while(g_Memory.Read<int32_t>(pUserCmd + 0x4) < iDesiredCmdNumber) // wait for the right usercmd to be accessed
{
    std::this_thread::yield();
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода на с++, для которого вы хотите найти альтернативу

Comment: Добавил пример @Евгений

Comment: `time.sleep(0)` можно для этого использовать.